# Enhanced for loop and iterator in Java

Tags: java, for-loop, iterator

I have a class MyList that implements `Iterable` interface. And here is a `toString()` method from one of my classes:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        // First example using iterator
        for (Iterator<Integer> itr = array[i].iterator(); itr.hasNext();) {
            sb.append(itr.next() + " ");
        }
        // And the same result using enhanced for loop
        for (int val : array[i]) {
            sb.append(val + " ");
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

This loop iterates over the nodes in my list:

```
for (int val : array[i]) {
    sb.append(val + " ");
}
```

How does this for loop uses the iterator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your class (`MyList`) implements `Iterable`. So internally it will call your `iterator()` method and then with the use of `hasNext()` and `next()` methods of ListIterator it will iterate in `for` loop.

Refer : [Using Enhanced For-Loops with Your Classes](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with)

Answer (score 1):

The enhanced for loop works for any class that implements `Iterable`. It internally calls the `iterator()` method implemented by that class to obtain an `Iterator`, and uses `hasNext()` and `next()` methods of the `Iterator` to iterate over the elements of the `Iterator`.